# Как из одного открытого cmd вписать что-то в другой открытый cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell, ffmpeg, timeout

У меня один bat вызывает другой bat по кругу до истечения перебора файлов. В первый закинул таймаут на примерное время работы второго bat.

Можно ли как-то прописать, чтобы вместо таймаута первый батник дальше продолжал работать после завершения второго?

Обдумав, решил, что есть вариант в конце второго bat прописать продолжение работы первого, стоячего на таймауте. Поэтому задался вопросом: как из одного открытого cmd вписать что-то в другой открытый cmd?

Из моих предположений: через powershell вызвать net-класс, найти окно по хандлеру или тайтлу, вызвать метод отправки строки/клавиш, но не понимаю как это реализовать в коде.

Может есть альтернативный вариант решения задачи, был бы рад услышать.

`for /R "vids" %%f in (*.mp4) do ( md temp & ffmpeg -i "%%f" "temp\%%~nf-.mp4" & start start.bat & timeout 30)`

Comment: Почитайте https://ab57.ru/cmdlist/start.html про `WAIT`. Думаю это то, что хотите

Comment: Спасибо большое! @MaxDown

Answer (score 1):

Добрый человек из комментариев подсказал.
`start /wait start.bat`